# Rails 4 - subdomains management

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain

I am working on an app where I need to manage subdomains.

while I am trying to get request's subdomain, i get nil even if there is one and get entire host with domain :

```
# GET patate.localhost:3000
request.subdomain # -> nil
request.subdomains # -> []
request.domain # -> patate.localhost
request.host # -> patate.localhost
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my approach ?

EDIT

My /etc/hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 patate.localhost
```

Comment: dont use subdomains on localhost

Comment: it is for development environnement. Shall I deduce that rails don't get subdomains on localhost?

Comment: I dont think its a rails pb

Comment: according to rails source, subdomain is managed by a split('.') http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-extract_subdomains

Comment: so you deduce its not a Rails pb right? you cant use subdomains on localhost, simply edit your host file

Comment: I am quite well redirected, the problem is that I have to do request.host.split('.')[0] to get the subdomain

Comment: this is correct, the pattern is: subdomains/name/extension. In you case, extension: localhost, name: patate, subdomain: none. => Dont use localhost...

Comment: how should I do for development purposes ? I didn't get your slashed stuff... There is no extension in ActionDispatch::Http::URL

Comment: request.host gives me 'patate.localhost' as said in question

Comment: do as I show in the answeer, it works for me, will work for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your host file:

```
127.0.0.1 patate.local.dev
```

Then work on `http://patate.local.dev:3000`, and you'll have a `patate` subdomain

Comment: :) localhost is just a special case I guess... no need to bother with it